# Async loading json as object property, then accessing it in an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-events

I have an object where I load some JSON during initialization. I also have a select that I attach an `onChange` event to. The `onChange` event function has to work with the object itself, but that object is stale. How do I work with the live or updated object?

```
var MyFancyObject = {
    init: function() {
        // set controls
        this.abc = // load some stuff async
        this.select.on('change', this.myEvent.call(this)); // attach my event 
    },

    myEvent: function() {
        console.log(this.abc); // undefined
    }
};
```

Comment: `this.myEvent.call(this)` calls a function immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler is not set up correctly.  It is called immediately rather than set up to be called when the event occurs.  You can change it to this:

```
var MyFancyObject = {
    init: function() {
        // set controls
        this.abc = // load some stuff async
        var self = this;
        this.select.on('change', function(e) {
            self.myEvent(e);
        }); // attach my event 
    },

    myEvent: function() {
        console.log(this.abc); // undefined
    }
};
```

Or, in modern browsers (IE9 or higher), you could use `.bind()`.

```
var MyFancyObject = {
    init: function() {
        // set controls
        this.abc = // load some stuff async
        this.select.on('change', this.myEvent.bind(this)); // attach my event 
    },

    myEvent: function() {
        console.log(this.abc); // undefined
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.myEvent.call(this)` calls the function. Instead you want to bind the function:

```
    this.select.on('change', this.myEvent.bind(this));
```